# Mac Mini still detects monitor when it is unplugged or turned off

Tags: display, mac-mini, hdmi

I have a Mac mini (2018) that continues to detect an HDMI connected monitor even after the monitor has been powered off/unplugged from power. When I unplug the HDMI cord it does remove it from my display arrangement, but this isn't helpful; I don't want to unplug my HDMI cord from my second monitor when I want to just focus on my main display.

I have already tried deleting the profile and rebooted many times.

Comment: So, you remove the power cable, but the Mac still detects a monitor?  This could be the cable and/or the monitor itself (residual charge).  Have you tried waiting for a little bit to see if the monitor goes away on it's own?  Which model monitor?  Which cable are you using?

Comment: I've observed the same thing on my 2018 Mini. Make sure you report it to Apple. There may not be a solution.

Comment: @Allan - yes the power cable has been removed - I don't think it's a residual charge because this has spanned several hours. Until the HDMI cord is detached it considers the monitor still there. This is the ASUS PB277Q.

Comment: Well, until we have that info, we have to ask.  Which cable are you using?

Comment: @Allan - are you asking which HDMI cable specifically? I have tried many, different brands, and the same behavior persists. Currently plugged in is: Zeskit’s Cinema Plus Series HDMI Cable.

Comment: Yes.  I'm trying to get an accurate picture of what you've got going on there so I can least do some cursory research.  Any computer/OS can't detect a device unless *something* is sending a signal.  So, for you to unplug a monitor from the mains and the signal to remain, *something* must be creating a signal that macOS sees.   All that said...I'm very much against HDMI in compute environments (IMO, it sucks).  The 2018 mini & your display support DisplayPort.  Try using a a [Type C DisplayPort cable](http://radnex.us/Cable-Matters-USB-C-Display-Port-Cable-4K).  There will no signal conversion

Comment: Now, looking at your HDMI cable, it's looks to be a quality cable, but it might not be working well with Apple's implementation of it.  Past experience tells me with consumer tech like HDMI, Apple doesn't play well.  Try the DP cable I linked and see if that solves the issue.

Comment: That would be my preferred connection - alas I am using Thunderbolt3/USB C for my primary monitor which is daisy chained via Display Port type C to a secondary monitor. When I try connecting another monitor via USB C - even on the other bus - it fails. HDMI is the only way this works. I should add that this is a new issue - I had the same monitor (same cords, and hookup) until a few days ago, which I replaced when it died with the same model monitor.